# Restoring undoManager of UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsundomanager

In my app I have a class inherited from `UITextView` and I need to create and destroy many instances of this view on screen. So my question - is there a way to save (before destroy) and then restore (after create) undo/redo stacks of each instance?

```
// After creation should be restoring like this.
// (This doesn't work certainly as undoManager is a readonly property)
self.undoManager = storedUndoManager;
```

Comment: I guess you could add them to an array or dictionary, and them access that way?

Comment: Thanks, @JomanJi. But what will exact restoring process be? How can I manipulate `undoManager` property of UITextView?

Comment: I would recommend creating a NSMutableDictionary property, and storing each `undoManager` with the key `tag` of the UITextView. Then, when you need to access it later on, you can request the `tag` from the dictionary to get the appropriate `undoManager`